# Efficiency of logical "or" on bool values in C++

Tags: c++, boolean, bitwise-operators

```
bool x = false, y = false, z = true;

if(x || y || z){}

or

if(x | y | z){}
```

Does the second if statement perform a bit wise "or" operation on all booleans? treating them as if there were bytes? ex) (0000 | 0000 | 0001) = true...

Or does it act like a Java | on booleans, where it will evaluate every bool in the expression even if the first was true?

I want to know how bit wise operators work on bool values. is it equivalent to integer bitwise operations?

Comment: Logical operators are more appropriate in cases such as this. Only worry about "efficiency" if and when you have established that there is a real need to.

Comment: Use whichever most clearly reflects the code logic.

Comment: i understand this, the reason im asking is i want to know how bit wise operators work on bool values. is it equivalent to integer bitwise operations?

Comment: @JavaNewb: Note that bitwise-OR, followed by test in boolean context, and coercion to bool followed by logical-OR, both give exactly the same result.  It's AND (and XOR) that is problematic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Efficiency depends, the logical or operator `||` is a short circuit operator
meaning if `x` in your example is true it will not evaluate `y` or `z`.
If it was a logical and `&&` then if `x` is false, it will not test `y` or `z`.
Its important to note that this operation does not exist as an instruction 
so that means you have to use test and jump instructions. This means  branching, which slows down things. Since modern CPU's are pipelined.

But the real answer is it depends, like many other questions of this nature, as sometimes the benefit of short circuiting operations outweighs the cost.

In the following extremely simple example you can see that bitwise or `|` is superior.

```
#include <iostream>


bool test1(bool a, bool b, bool c)
{
    return a | b | c;
}

bool test2(bool a, bool b, bool c)
{
    return a || b || c;
}

int main()
{
  bool a = true;
  bool b = false;
  bool c = true;
  test1(a,b,c);
  test2(a,b,c);
  return 0;
}
```

The following is the intel-style assembly listings produced by gcc-4.8 with `-O3` :
`test1` assembly :

```
_Z5test1bbb:
.LFB1264:
    .cfi_startproc
    mov eax, edx
    or  eax, esi
    or  eax, edi
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

`test2` assembly :

```
_Z5test2bbb:
.LFB1265:
    .cfi_startproc
    test    dil, dil
    jne .L6
    test    sil, sil
    mov eax, edx
    jne .L6
    rep; ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L6:
    mov eax, 1
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

You can see that it has branch instructions, which mess up the pipeline.

Sometimes however short-circuiting is worth it such as

`return x && deep_recursion_function();`

**Disclaimer:**

I would always use logical operators on `bools`. Unless performance really is critical, or maybe simple case like in `test1` and `test2` but with lots of bools.
And in either case first verify that you do get an improvement.

Answer (score 3):

The second acts a java | on integers, a bit-wise or.  As C originally didn't have a boolean type, the if statement reads any non-zero as true, so you can use it as that, but it is often more efficient to use the short-circuiting operator || instead, especially when calling functions that return the conditions.

I would also like to point out that short-circuit lets you check unsafe conditions, like `if(myptr == NULL || myptr->struct_member < 0) return -1;`, while using the bitwise or there will give you a segfault when myptr **is** null.